# Pass parameter to DAX query with Power BI REST API and Python

Tags: python, powerbi, dax, powerbi-rest-api

The following Python script is written to access the data in the Power BI data warehouse externally.

```js
import json
import requests
from cred import username, password, client_id, client_secret, scope, token_endpoint,url
from dax_query import dax_query

payload = {
    "grant_type": "password",
    "client_id": client_id,
    "client_secret": client_secret,
    "resource": scope,
    "username": username,
    "password": password,
}

# Define the getToken function
def getToken():
    response = requests.post(token_endpoint, data=payload)
    response_data = response.json()
    access_token = response_data.get("access_token")

    if access_token:
        return access_token
    else:
        print("Failed to obtain access token.")
        exit(1)

# Call getToken to get the access token
access_token = getToken()

headers = {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
}

payload_data = {
    "queries": [
        {
            "query": dax_query,
        }
    ],
    "serializerSettings": {
        "includeNulls": True,
    },
}
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(payload_data))
print(response.text)
print("Response Status Code:", response.status_code)  # Add this line for debugging

if response.status_code == 200:
    print("Response Text:", response.text)
else:
    print("Error Occurred. Response Text:", response.text)
```

The relavent DAX query (dax_query) is included in dax_query.py file

```html
dax_query = "Evaluate SUMMARIZE( 'axp_gw_succes_faild', 'axp_gw_succes_faild'[Date], 'axp_gw_succes_faild'[api_publisher], 'axp_gw_succes_faild'[application_name], 'axp_gw_succes_faild'[api_name],\"TotalCount\", CALCULATE (SUM ( axp_gw_succes_faild[Count] ),FILTER('Publisher-UserDetails','Publisher-UserDetails'[BAdashboard_authoritylevel] = \"Publisher\"|| 'Publisher-UserDetails'[BAdashboard_authoritylevel] = \"publisherTechLead\"|| 'Publisher-UserDetails'[BAdashboard_authoritylevel] = \"publisherArchitect\"||'Publisher-UserDetails'[BAdashboard_authoritylevel] = \"ProductOwner\"),'Publisher-UserDetails'[User-Email]=@user, GROUPBY (axp_gw_succes_faild,axp_gw_succes_faild[api_name],axp_gw_succes_faild[Date] )))"
```

**I want to send the user as a parameter value 'Publisher-UserDetails'[User-Email]=@user)**

**Can You suggest a solution to improve the script?**